# Blink Refuse to render ALL css after progress::-moz-progress-bar{}?

Tags: html, css

I am styling an HTML [progress] element. I'm nesting my css rules.

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

form {
    
    progress::-webkit-progress-value { background-color: orange; }
    
    progress::-moz-progress-bar { background-color: orange; }

    input {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      min-height: 35px;
    }

    ... more css rules ...
} /* form */
```

This works fine in Firefox, but Chrome and Edge stop rendering ALL css rules after `progress::-moz-progress-bar {}` which results in a broken layout.

I ended up placing `progress::-moz-progress-bar {}` at the very end of my stylesheet, which works, but it sure would be nice not to have to do that. Does anyone know of a fix?

Comment: It's because it's a [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-progress-bar) pseudo selector. Chrome and Edge will choke and stop - as you've found out. What's the concern with placing it at the bottom of your stylesheet if it works? Also, both of those selectors clearly state not to use them on production sites on their respective MDN pages. _Does anyone know of a fix?_ place it at the end of your stylesheet :)

Comment: you need to share the full code, we the to see the "more CSS rules" because I am pretty sure the issue is there

Comment: @disinfor those selectors are fine to use, there are browser specific and CSS after them should also work fine. The issue is for sure somewhere else (related: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-style-a-progress-bar-using-css)

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah, they are fine - but I recently came across a similar issue with FF compatibility with Chrome/Edge or vise versa. I'll see if I can find the issue (it was here on SO)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It encouraged me to investigate more deeply. The issue only happens when using CSS nesting. When I don't nest css rules, there is no issue. I will write an answer describing this I guess.

Comment: you need to share the full code before, there is no nesting in your question so it doesn't make sense to write an answer about an "invisible" issue

Comment: Oh, OK I'll update my original question

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the issue only happens when nesting CSS rules.

This works cross browser:

```css
body,
html
{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

body *
{ box-sizing: border-box; }

form {
    --bg: rgb(245,245,245);
    --text: rgb(60,60,60);
    --border: silver;
    --accent: lime;
    --min: 2.5rem;
    --pad: .5rem;
}

/*********************/
/**** Backgrounds ****/
/*********************/

button,
input,
progress,
progress::-webkit-progress-bar
{ background-color: var(--bg); }

progress::-webkit-progress-value 
{ background-color: var(--accent); }

progress::-moz-progress-bar 
{ background-color: var(--accent); }

/*********************/
/****** Borders ******/
/*********************/

button,
fieldset,
input,
progress
{ border: 1px solid var(--border); }

button,
fieldset,
input,
progress
{ border-radius: .5rem; }

/******************************/
/*********** Accent ***********/
/******************************/
input,
progress
{ accent-color: var(--accent); }

/******************************/
/************ Text ************/
/** Color/Size/Weight/Shadow **/
/******************************/

button,
input,
fieldset,
label,
legend
{
  color: var(--text);
  font-size: 1rem;
}

button,
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"],
label,
legend
{ font-weight:bold; }

/*********************/
/***** Structure *****/
/*********************/

button
{
  min-height: var(--min);
  padding: var(--pad);
}

button,
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"]
{
  margin: .25rem;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

div > *
{ margin: 0; }

fieldset
{ padding: var(--pad); }

fieldset > div
{ margin: 0; }

input
{
  min-height: var(--min);
  padding: var(--pad);
}

label
{ white-space: nowrap; }

progress
{
  appearance: none;
  height: 1.5rem;
  overflow: clip;
  width: 100%;
}

.column
{ flex-direction: column; }

.column.reverse
{ flex-direction: column-reverse; }

.row
{
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row > *
{
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.row > input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"])
{ flex: 2 }

.row.reverse
{ flex-direction: row-reverse; }
```

```html
<form action="/foo/">
  <div class="row">
        <div>
      <label for="givenname">Given Name</label>
      <input id="givenname" name="givenname">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="familyname">Family Name</label>
      <input id="familyname" name="familyname">
    </div>
  </div>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>progress</legend>
    <progress value="50" max="100" id="progress"></progress>
  </fieldset>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset">
</form>
```

This breaks Chromium/Blink

```css
body,
html
{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

body *
{ box-sizing: border-box; }

form {
    --bg: rgb(245,245,245);
    --text: rgb(60,60,60);
    --border: silver;
    --accent: lime;
    --min: 2.5rem;
    --pad: .5rem;

    /*********************/
    /**** Backgrounds ****/
    /*********************/

    button,
    input,
    progress,
    progress::-webkit-progress-bar
    { background-color: var(--bg); }

    progress::-webkit-progress-value 
    { background-color: var(--accent); }

    progress::-moz-progress-bar 
    { background-color: var(--accent); }

    /*********************/
    /****** Borders ******/
    /*********************/

    button,
    fieldset,
    input,
    progress
    { border: 1px solid var(--border); }

    button,
    fieldset,
    input,
    progress
    { border-radius: .5rem; }

    /******************************/
    /*********** Accent ***********/
    /******************************/
    input,
    progress
    { accent-color: var(--accent); }

    /******************************/
    /************ Text ************/
    /** Color/Size/Weight/Shadow **/
    /******************************/

    button,
    input,
    fieldset,
    label,
    legend
    {
      color: var(--text);
      font-size: 1rem;
    }

    button,
    input[type="reset"],
    input[type="submit"],
    label,
    legend
    { font-weight:bold; }

    /*********************/
    /***** Structure *****/
    /*********************/

    button
    {
      min-height: var(--min);
      padding: var(--pad);
    }

    button,
    input[type="reset"],
    input[type="submit"]
    {
      margin: .25rem;
      overflow-wrap: anywhere;
    }

    div {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: .5rem;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 1rem 0;
    }

    div > *
    { margin: 0; }

    fieldset
    { padding: var(--pad); }

    fieldset > div
    { margin: 0; }

    input
    {
      min-height: var(--min);
      padding: var(--pad);
    }

    label
    { white-space: nowrap; }

    progress
    {
      appearance: none;
      height: 1.5rem;
      overflow: clip;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .column
    { flex-direction: column; }

    .column.reverse
    { flex-direction: column-reverse; }

    .row
    {
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .row > *
    {
      flex: 1;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .row > input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"])
    { flex: 2 }

    .row.reverse
    { flex-direction: row-reverse; }
    
} /* form */
```

```html
<form action="/foo/">
  <div class="row">
        <div>
      <label for="givenname">Given Name</label>
      <input id="givenname" name="givenname">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="familyname">Family Name</label>
      <input id="familyname" name="familyname">
    </div>
  </div>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>progress</legend>
    <progress value="50" max="100" id="progress"></progress>
  </fieldset>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset">
</form>
```

HOWEVER, if you place `progress::-moz-progress-bar {}` at the END of the stylesheet, it still works.